# How to disable the submit button in form using Validation in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, kendo-ui

I have a form of 2 input fields with dropdown options. How can I disable the submit button until and unless both the fields are filled correctly

```
<form method="POST" id="formcheck">
   <label>first</label>
   <select class="" id="first" name="first"></select>
   <label>second</label>
   <select class="" id="second" name="second"></select>
   <input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In my js file I have written this, is this correct?

```
$("#first").kendoValidator();

$("#second").kendoValidator();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Client-side form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) documentation to understand the basics of form validation.

Then look at Telerik's [Validator Overview](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/validator/overview) documentation and the Validator [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/index).

You can use the `required` attribute to make an input mandatory.

```html
<form method="POST" id="formcheck">
   <label>first</label>
   <select class="" id="first" name="first" required></select>

   <label>second</label>
   <select class="" id="second" name="second" required></select>

   <input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then use the validator on the form.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var validator = $("#formcheck").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

        $("form").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if (validator.validate()) {
                console.log('form is valid');
            } else {
                console.log('form is NOT valid');                
            }
        });
    });
</script
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in vanilla js):

```js
let checkSelectFields = () => 
{
  let submitOk = true,
      selectFields = document.querySelectorAll('select'),
      i = 0;
      
  for (i; i < selectFields.length; i++) {
    if (!selectFields[i].value) { 
      submitOk = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  document.querySelector('#submitForm').disabled = !submitOk;
};

document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(select => select.addEventListener('change', checkSelectFields));

checkSelectFields();
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="formcheck">
   <label>first</label>
   <select class="" id="first" name="first"><option></option><option>Opt 1</option></select>
   <label>second</label>
   <select class="" id="second" name="second"><option></option><option>Opt 1</option></select>
   <input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit">
</form>
```